# MVC 5 Area Hide Home Controller in Url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a few areas in MVC 5 and each area has it's own HomeController.
So URL looks like:

```
/domain/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
/domain/myarea/home/myaction
```

Is it possible to configure routes to hide home controller name for each area? So the URL should look like:
`/domain/myarea/myaction` - pointed to the home controller in area of course.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: you can map a new route in the routeconfig.cs file. The new route would only contain the action parameter withh it.And make sure the more specific route is placed on the top priority of routeconfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update the route pattern for your area registration to remove the controller name.

For example  :

```
public class EventsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Events";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Events_default",
            "Events/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new string[] { "MyProject.Areas.Events.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Now the request  `yourSite/Events/Details/23` will return Details action method of HomeController in your Events area.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible.

You'll need to configure the route as

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "root",
    pattern: "{area}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { area = "MyArea", controller = "Home", action = "MyAction" });
```

If it matches the default controller, the controller name will not show in the url.